# Is there a javadoc replacement that uses a Wiki-like syntax?

Tags: java, documentation, wiki, javadoc

Is there a tool replacing javadoc with something that is more Wiki-style syntax instead of the HTMLish syntax of normal JavaDoc?

One of my problems is that I mostly read JavaDoc in source form. Even for external libraries I try to have the source attached so I can navigate into it from my IDE, checking the documentation above the entry point and if necessary the code below.

The other problem is that things like lists and code samples are messy to write, especially if your IDE insists on putting stars on every line. What I would like to see is something that uses a kind of Wiki syntax with at least the following features:

- lists
- code blocks
- crosslinking to methods/classes

There are many more things that would be nice, but I believe these are the essentials.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: Code blocks aren't too bad with `{@code }`. I think `{@link }` works reasonably well to link to members and types.

Comment: while you're thinking about wiki-style display, would be plenty nice if you could edit it wiki-style as well, and shove it back into the comments.  I suspect that's asking a bit much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project called [WikiDoclet](http://paulhorman.com/wikidoclet/), I have never used it, but I'd be interested to see what you think of it.

From the site:

> This is an extension to the standard javadoc doclet provided with the Java JDK. It adds support for what I am calling Wiki formatting. What this means is that your JavaDoc can now be formatted using text rules that are easier on the eyes than html embedded in JavaDoc. For example, to put emphasis on a piece of text you surround it with *stars*. Italics with *underscores*. When the doclet is run to produce JavaDoc these rules are evaluated and html substitutions are made. This formatting should make reading java source code much easier since it will no longer be cluttered with HTML tags. This is especially true for bulleted lists and for tables. HTML is preserved still though, so you can mix and match as you like.

For other doclet formats, check out [doclet.com](http://doclet.com/).

Comment: Nice links -- thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

now here: http://code.google.com/p/wikidoclet/